# Membership not using default provider

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-membership

Yesterday I configured my WPF app to use `Membership`. Everything was working fine. Today I start working again, and first I can't connect to my database; turns out I don't have SQL Server installed. I install SQL Server 2012 Express, and my app is still not working working properly.

This is my config. Nothing has changed since yesterday when it was working.:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
        <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="60">
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add
                  name="SqlProvider"
                  type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
                  connectionStringName="SamenSterker"
                  enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
                  enablePasswordReset="true"
                  requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
                  requiresUniqueEmail="true"
                  passwordFormat="Hashed"
                  minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
                  minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
                  maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="100"
                  passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
            </providers>
        </membership>
    </system.web>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="SamenSterker" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=GH2_SQLserver;Integrated Security=True" providerName=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

When I'm stepping through my program, I can see which provider it is using, and it seems it is using the standard provider, not my default. Does anyone know why it might not be using my default provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have solved it, but I don't understand it. The project exists out of an application and a service. The service talks with the sql server, and thus needs the membership provider. This is how I did it yesterday.

Today, however, my application suddenly needs the default provider, while it doesn't connect to the sql server.